The "2" key isn't working while i hold the control key
The "2" key isn't working while I hold the control key, but while im not holding control it works and I don't know how to resolve it.
I am using a brand new laptop.
I have tried using a different keyboard but it still doesn't work
Im expecting to get the number 2 as outcome.

Most likely harware fault on the keyboard. Can you test it on another device?

I am using a laptop

Try a different keyboard connected to the laptop. Also, does the issue happen when you use a different OS (use a "live" bootable Linux like Ubuntu if you don't have dual-boot already set up)./

I am on a laptop

That's not what I asked and having a laptop does not mean that you cannot connect a different keyboard. Get a keyboard, connect it to your laptop, and test.

I have a small desk and no space for one

That doesn't matter. When diagnosing issues with your laptop keyboard, the correct and necessary thing to do is to get a different keyboard and try using it. This will tell you whether the problem is limited to the laptop's keyboard or whether it is in the system software. If you will not do this, I don't think we can help you here.

I tried using another keyboard and it still doesn't work

it works with the other numbers but not with 2 the laptop is brand new

Good, now add that information to your question. But note: the quality of replies you get here will be directly dependent on the quality of information you give us. If you misrepresent what you have observed, we will not have accurate information, and so we will not be able to get you accurate replies.

If the laptop is brand new, take it back.

the 2 key works when im not holding control tho

There are apps that will show what keystrokes you have made.  In linux "xev" is one.  Using this you can see if the problem is with your keyboard or with your system.

Im using windows 11

If I open notepad.exe, and try to "type" Ctrl+2, it doesn't do anything... are you trying to use a keyboard shortcut, or expecting to see a 2 character? If the former, please specify the application, and verify that the shortcut is indeed setup. If you've actually tried another keyboard, then it's not a hardware issue and must be a software problem.

I use control to sprint and the 2 to equip the item in the second hotbar slot and it doesn't work that's the main reason why i asked in the first place

Im expecting to get the number 2 as outcome

How do I disable the shortcut

It sounds like both your Ctrl key and 2 key work from what you have stated. Either another application is interpreting this and not letting your game see it like others have said or perhaps the game you are using it on doesn't have that key combination set up? Many games you must specify the keyboard layout to do different moves such as sprinting. Simpler games do not allow more than one key per command so it sounds like it could possibly be how your game is set up and have nothing to do with the hardware itself.

When you test in-game, are you pressing other keys at the same time? We might be having a Key rollover issue. You can easily test whether this is the case by going to https://keyboard-test.space/ and pressing only CRTL and 2 at the same time. Both should light up blue on the website.

why do you expect a 2? ... ctrl-2 may be unprintable

@ZdravkoTsikandelov - “Im expecting to get the number 2 as outcome” - In what application? It refreshes the first tab in Edge, does nothing in Notepad, so what it does is entirely up to the developer of the application. Based only tests it absolutely does not result in 2 being printed. You need to clarify your question by editing your question and stop using the comment section to respond to our questions.

If you can type 2 and @, but Ctrl2 and CtrlShift2, then the most likely cause of the issue is an application such as AutoHotkey or Clavier+ is "stealing" those key presses.
To determine if the issue is in the keyboard, instead, plug in another USB keyboard. If that works, then replace the broken one.

@ presumes a certain keyboard layout (for me Shift+2 is ")

it isn't from the keyboard i tried a different one and it still doesn't work

How do i disable the AutoHotkey or the Clavier

You would have installed them; you would have to make the change.
